# Summernote Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Under a very specific set of circumstances I'm getting "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'" when invoking the pasteHTML() method on a Summernote object.

I want to emphasize that outside of the very specific circumstance described below, everything I'm doing works perfectly.  This is important to remember because the 'trigger' for the error makes no sense at all.

I have a web app that implements a custom messaging system, create, read, reply, etc.  The Summernote editor is used for composition.  When the 'Reply' button is clicked, the original message is added to the Summernote editor (via the pasteHTML() method).  Again, this works (usually).  I can come to the page, read messages, page around and when I go to reply to a given message, it works as designed (usually).

Now to the circumstance where the problem occurs. And this is the only circumstance where I can get the error to pop.

If, (and this is where it gets crazy and yes I can replicate this) if I click ANYWHERE on the page, blank space, text, really anywhere, prior to clicking the Reply button (again, which normally works) and then click the Reply button, the error pops.

To review; load page, click on any non-interactive area of the page, click Reply (which invokes the pasteHTML() method, the error pops.

So my question is; what could possibly be happening when I click on 'dead space' of the page to affect the subsequent calls to pasteHTML().

Here is the actual error from the browser console:

```
dom.js:398 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
at insertAfter (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:1079:18)
at splitNode (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:1408:23)
at https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:1451:18
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at splitTree (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:1447:24)
at Object.splitPoint (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:1481:32)
at WrappedRange.insertNode (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:2150:26)
at https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:2170:26
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at WrappedRange.pasteHTML (https://localhost:44328/lib/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js:2169:35)
insertAfter @ dom.js:397
splitNode @ dom.js:761
(anonymous) @ dom.js:809
splitTree @ dom.js:804
splitPoint @ dom.js:840
WrappedRange.insertNode @ range.js:518
(anonymous) @ range.js:541
WrappedRange.pasteHTML @ range.js:540
(anonymous) @ Editor.js:140
(anonymous) @ Editor.js:597
Context.invoke @ Context.js:227
summernote @ summernote.js:37
(anonymous) @ messaging.js?v=45N8mkloxmbpeQNrnX0KaIQaIrl7_lzbhcOQ1JECSnw:133
dispatch @ jquery.js:5233
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5040
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, I corrected the behavior by making sure that the 'summernote' control was visible before pasting the HTML.

Now, why the behavior manifested only when clicking on a dead area of the page, is beyond me, but I was able to work around it.